# functional array list search

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Having issues displaying what I am searching for in my array list. When I search the array it finds the information but it prints the whole list do to all the objects being named fisherman. It will search for the item and if found will print the items I am wanting but it prints ALL the instances of fisherman.  But the search is clunky and doesnt work in some instances. So, I am needing help with the search function to do a proper search and output of that search. I am not sure how I would go about changing the object name from "fisherman" to the SSN of each fisherman then that would help in the searching parameters. But I couldn't figure out a way to change the object name for each individual fisherman. Thank you for any help you can provide.

```
public static void fishermanMenu() {
    // declare variables and array
    int selection;
    String fName;
    String lName;
    String ssn;
    String number;
    String email;
    String searchSSN;
    String menuFisherman[] = {"Register New Fisherman", "Search Fisherman", "Return to Main Menu"};

    System.out.println("\nFisherman Menu");
    // for loop to print menu from array
    for(int i = 0, k = 1; i < menuFisherman.length; i++, k++) {
        System.out.println("("+ k + ") " + (menuFisherman[i]));    
    }
    System.out.print("Selection: ");
    selection = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    if (selection == 1) {       
        $Fisherman fisherman = new $Fisherman();
        fishermen.add(fisherman);

        System.out.print("Enter First Name: ");
        fName = input.next();
        fisherman.setFirstName(fName);

        System.out.print("Enter Last Name: ");
        lName = input.next();
        fisherman.setLastName(lName);

        System.out.print("Enter Phone Number...ie 904-560-7896: ");
        number = input.next();
        fisherman.setPhoneNumber(number);

        System.out.print("Enter SSN...ie 123-45-6789: ");
        ssn = input.next();
        fisherman.setSSN(ssn);

        System.out.print("Enter email address: ");
        email = input.next();
        fisherman.setEmailAddress(email);

        System.out.print(fishermen.toString());

        fishermanMenu();
    }

    else if (selection == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter Social Security Number of fisherman to search for below.");
        System.out.print("SSN: ");
        searchSSN = input.nextLine();

        for ($Fisherman fisherman : fishermen) {
            if (fisherman.getSSN().equals(searchSSN)) {
                System.out.println(fishermen.toString());
                fishermanMenu();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No match for that fisherman");
                fishermanMenu();
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

here is the output. As you can see when I searched for "123" it returned the whole list and when I searched for "456" it said "No match for that fisherman".

```
    Main Menu
    (1) Fisherman Menu
    (2) Tournament Menu
    (3) Fish Menu
    (4) Close Tournament
    (5) Quit Program
    Selection: 1

    Fisherman Menu
    (1) Register New Fisherman
    (2) Search Fisherman
    (3) Return to Main Menu
    Selection: 1
    Enter First Name: Matt
    Enter Last Name: P
    Enter Phone Number...ie 904-560-7896: 123
    Enter SSN...ie 123-45-6789: 123
    Enter email address: 123

    [fisherman{SSN=123, firstName='Matt', lastName='P', phoneNumber='123', emailAddress='123'}]

    Fisherman Menu
    (1) Register New Fisherman
    (2) Search Fisherman
    (3) Return to Main Menu
    Selection: 1
    Enter First Name: Joe
    Enter Last Name: K
    Enter Phone Number...ie 904-560-7896: 456
    Enter SSN...ie 123-45-6789: 456
    Enter email address: 456

    [fisherman{SSN=123, firstName='Matt', lastName='P', phoneNumber='123', emailAddress='123'}, fisherman{SSN=456, firstName='Joe', lastName='K', phoneNumber='456', emailAddress='456'}]

    Fisherman Menu
    (1) Register New Fisherman
    (2) Search Fisherman
    (3) Return to Main Menu
    Selection: 2
    Enter Social Security Number of fisherman to search for below.
    SSN: 123
    [fisherman{SSN=123, firstName='Matt', lastName='P', phoneNumber='123', emailAddress='123'}, fisherman{SSN=456, firstName='Joe', lastName='K', phoneNumber='456', emailAddress='456'}]

    Fisherman Menu
    (1) Register New Fisherman
    (2) Search Fisherman
    (3) Return to Main Menu
    Selection: 2
    Enter Social Security Number of fisherman to search for below.
    SSN: 456
    No match for that fisherman

    Fisherman Menu
    (1) Register New Fisherman
    (2) Search Fisherman
    (3) Return to Main Menu
    Selection:
```

Comment: Small suggestion here: Java convention discourages the use of "$" in identifiers, except for either legacy or machine-generated code. Read about it in the Java Language Spec [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are printing `fishermen.toString()` which is the whole list.

```
System.out.println(fishermen.toString());
```

Change the above to print `fisherman.toString()` instead

**EDIT:**

You are using `if-else` for each fisherman in the loop, you need to fix that as the following:

```
int found = 0;
for ($Fisherman fisherman : fishermen) {
    if (fisherman.getSSN().equals(searchSSN)) {
        found = 1;
        System.out.println(fisherman);
        break;
    }
if (found == 0) {
    System.out.println("No match for that fisherman");
    fishermanMenu();               
}
else {
    found = 0;
    fishermanMenu();
}
```

Comment: I changed the `(fishermen.toString())` to just `(fisherman)` and it now only prints the one that is being entered or searched for as I wanted. However, I am still not getting a return for searching for "456" and runs straight to the "No match for that fisherman" but works well when searching for "123".

Comment: @MatthewPhaneuf This is because you are using `if-else` for each fisherman, I have updated my answer to fix that please check it out and let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    private static List<Fisherman> allFisherpeople = new ArrayList<Fisherman>();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        while (true) {
            printMenu();

            String selection = getInput();
            if ("1".equals(selection)) {
                addFisherman();
            } else if ("2".equals(selection)) {
                searchFishermen();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a vaild selection: " + selection);
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getInput() {
        try {
            String string = new String();
            char character;
            while ((character = (char) System.in.read()) != '\n')
                string += character;
            return string;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void printMenu() {
        String menuFisherman[] = { "Register New Fisherman", "Search Fisherman", "Return to Main Menu" };
        System.out.println("\nFisherman Menu");
        for (int i = 0; i < menuFisherman.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("(" + (i + 1) + ") " + (menuFisherman[i]));
        }
        System.out.print("Selection: ");
    }

    private static void addFisherman() {
        Fisherman fisherman = new Fisherman();
        System.out.print("Enter First Name: ");
        fisherman.setFirstName(getInput());
        System.out.print("Enter Last Name: ");
        fisherman.setLastName(getInput());
        System.out.print("Enter Phone Number...ie 904-560-7896: ");
        fisherman.setPhoneNumber(getInput());
        System.out.print("Enter SSN...ie 123-45-6789: ");
        fisherman.setSsn(getInput());
        System.out.print("Enter email address: ");
        fisherman.setEmail(getInput());
        System.out.print(fisherman);
        allFisherpeople.add(fisherman);
    }

    private static void searchFishermen() {
        System.out.println("Enter Social Security Number of fisherman to search for below.");
        System.out.print("SSN: ");
        String search = getInput();

        for (Fisherman fisherman : allFisherpeople) {
            if (fisherman.getSsn().equals(search)) {
                System.out.println("You must be looking for: " + fisherman);
            } else {
                System.out.println("No match for that fisherman");
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Fisherman {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String ssn;
        private String phoneNumber;
        private String email;

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getSsn() {
            return ssn;
        }

        public void setSsn(String ssn) {
            this.ssn = ssn;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return firstName + " " + lastName + " (" + phoneNumber + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The way you have it coded you're getting deeper recursively into your method. System.out.println(obj) already does a toString on it so no need to write System.out.println(obj.toString()). I never use std in so take any of that with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. After a few hours away and a fresh set of eyes and your comment I was able to see the issues. I changed the code on lines 44 and 56 from `(fishermen.toString())` to just `(fisherman)` and that fixed the issue of printing ALL the fisherman each time. Also changed that else statement to a single print statement outside the for loop. This allowed the search to go through the entire list and not just the first fisherman before printing the "No match for that fisherman".

```
    else if (selection == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter Social Security Number of fisherman to search for below.");
        System.out.print("SSN: ");
        searchSSN = input.nextLine();

        for ($Fisherman fisherman : fishermen) {
            if (fisherman.getSSN().equals(searchSSN)) {
                System.out.println(fisherman);
                fishermanMenu();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No match for that fisherman");
        fishermanMenu();
    }
```